# Regular Expression With Unique Digits

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression with Unique digits separated with comma with max 5 digit and numbers are allowed from 1-10. for example

**1,2,3,4,5 - valid**

**1,2,2,4,5 - Invalid** (Because it's allowing to define duplicate digits)

but I want regular expression in which we can enter only unique number.
I am mentioning below my regex which allow digits with comma separated and allow 5 digits between 1-10.

**^([1-9]|10)(?:,([1-9]|10)){0,4}$**

Please help how to define this regex which allow only unique digits

Comment: You might use `^(?!.*\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b)(?:[1-9]|10)(?:,(?:[1-9]|10)){0,4}$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Isn’t that going to slip `1,2,2,4,5` through (which it shouldn’t)? I haven’t tested.

Comment: kamal, while this is possible, I don’t think a regular expression is the best tool for the job.

Comment: @OleV.V. I tested, it does not allow `2,2`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You have answered the question and may want to post that as an answer. [Tested online](https://ideone.com/NHt3y9). But please incluse proper explanation. It’s not clear to less experienced regular expression users how it works.

Comment: Another idea: [`^(?:([1-9]|10),?\b(?!.*?\b\1\b)){1,5}$`](https://regex101.com/r/xGT5zj/2) or [at regexplanet](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyy54fqyr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?!.*\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b)(?:[1-9]|10)(?:,(?:[1-9]|10)){0,4}$
```

See an [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FePJvi/1).

The `(?!.*\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b)` negative lookahead fails any match if there are repeated identical digit chunks as whole words (enclosed with word boundary positions).

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/DWjSzB):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("1,2,3,4,5", "1,2,2,4,5");
String rx = "(?!.*\\b(\\d+)\\b.*\\b\\1\\b)(?:[1-9]|10)(?:,(?:[1-9]|10)){0,4}";
for (String str : strs)
    System.out.println(str + ": " + str.matches(rx));
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4,5: true
1,2,2,4,5: false
```

Note that `^` and `$` at the start and end of the pattern are omitted in Java code since `.matches` requires a full string match.